# Excel - splitting multiline cells into columns but keep relevant data grouped on same column

Tags: excel

I have a column full of multiline addresses and I'm trying to split them into separate columns. Some are written on 3 lines like this:

```
123 Main Street
America City, NY 10000
USA
```

And some are written on 4 lines like this:

```
456 Broadway
Suite 1000
Football Town, TX 55555
USA
```

I know I can use text to columns and use ALT0010 as the delimiter to separate these out, but the problem I'm having is I would like to have all the (city,state) lines and the (USA) lines match up in the same column, but about half the addresses have that second address line of suite or floor which misaligns these columns. Is there any way to split it so that if it has 4 lines or breaks in the cell it goes into columns A,B,C,D, but if it has 3 lines then they go into A,C,D, leaving B blank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column.  Put this formula in cell B1 and copy down:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))=2,SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(CHAR(10),2),1),A1)
```

That will add the missing Suite/Apt # line as a blank line if it doesn't exist, and will do nothing if it's already there.  Then, copy/paste your helper column as values and you can do a text-to-columns on the new column using ALT-010 as the delimiter.

Comment: Your other option is to use formulas to split out the data to where you want it.